# DAG graph where indegree >= outdegree and indegree = 0 => outdegree <= 1, cover all vertex with min amount of paths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dag

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ where

1. G is directed: $ \forall \ e \in E$ : $e$ has a direction.
2. G is acyclic (no cycles): $ \forall$ path $v_1, \dots , v_n : (v_n, v_1) \not\in E $.
3. If indegree $\gt0$, indegree $\ge$ outdegree: $ \forall \ v \in V : d^{-1}(v) \gt0\implies d^{-1}(v) \ge d^{+1}(v) $.
4. If indegree $=$ $0$, outdegree is $\le 1$: $ \forall \ v \in V : d^{-1}(v) = 0 \implies d^{+1}(v) \le 1 $.

The problem is to find the min. amount of paths which cover all vertexes.

My solution is this:
The min. amount of paths which cover all vertexes is the amount of vertexes with indegree 0.

Proof: 
Property 1 and 2 follows that G is a DAG (directed acyclic graph). 
Property 3 and 4 follows 
a) that each "start" vertex (indegree = 0) can either have 0 or 1 connected edges 
b) There is never a bigger outdegree than indegree

Step 1: Using all paths starting at vertexes with indegree 0 is the min. amount of paths. 
Since the graph is a DAG, there will exist at least one vertex with indegree 0.
As those vertexes v with $ d^{-1}(v) = 0 $ (indegree 0) cannot be covered from any path not starting at v, all of them will have to be the starting vertex of a path.

Step 2: Each vertex is covert using all paths starting at vertexes with indegree 0. 
Each start vertex v has either 0 or 1 edges. 
case 0: 
Path is over. 
case 1: 
The edge connects to one vertex b. For each incoming edge there is at most 1 one edge going out. Take any of them in the path and the path will have a finite size since there a no cycles. Since each starting vertex has a vertex b which has at most one outgoing edge per in coming edge, this argument holds by induction. Meaning, every vertex has a connection (going backwards) to a starting vertex.

Now, I'd like to get some feedback: Is this proof correct, are there some mistakes, what could I do better?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: No. It's not true. Note that, if such a graph has a directed path which covers all of vertices then it has at most one vertex with indegree=0 and outdegree=1. In fact, by deleting such a vertex, we have a graph where for all of vertices v indegree(v)=outdegree(v).